# the entity type is not part of the model for the current context strange error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

My DB context initialization is as below. Everything works fine. After stop and restart project on visual studio debug mode the error 'the entity 'x' type is not part of the model for the current context' occurs for the same operation.In debug mode, I see this 'x' entityType is invoked.

But if I rebuild entity project everything works fine until next debug restart.

Any idea?

```
public class FsDbContext : DataContext<DbContext>, ITransientDataContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //MappingAssemblies.All.ForEach(assembly => modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(assembly));

        var addMethod = typeof(ConfigurationRegistrar).GetMethods().Single(m => m.Name == "Add"
            && m.GetGenericArguments().Any(a => a.Name == "TEntityType"));

        MappingAssemblies.All.ForEach(assembly =>
        {
            var configTypes = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.BaseType != null 
                && t.BaseType.IsGenericType 
                && t.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(EntityTypeConfiguration<>));

            foreach (var type in configTypes)
            {
                var entityType = type.BaseType.GetGenericArguments().Single();

                var entityConfig = assembly.CreateInstance(type.FullName);
                addMethod.MakeGenericMethod(entityType)
                  .Invoke(modelBuilder.Configurations, new object[] { entityConfig });
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you load entity assembly dynamically do not use

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
```

Use

```
Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.dll")
```